# A report of refactoring recommendations

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, add-in

I'm working on an old site that needs to be optimised, I've installed Refactor! and its coming up with lots of recommendations, including lots of instances where objects aren't disposed off.  Is there a way to create a report of these recommendations or another tool that I could use?

Thanks,
Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this 3rd party plugin may be your best bet

http://code.google.com/p/dxcorecommunityplugins/wiki/CodeIssueAnalysis

As yet, there is no PDF export from this util, but I imagine that this might not take much to add. I'll ping the author and try to find out.

**Update:** I have asked the original author of this plugin about this  and whilst there appear to be no export facilities associated with the Grid he is using, he suggests he's quite keen on providing an export to Csv or html or similar.

So I suggest you keep an eye on the wiki page for the plugin and see what develops